# How to find images in online directory?

Tags: java, android, directory

Suppose there is a URL like -> ...`/sample/photos/` and this directory contains pictures. How via android (Java) i can see and get these photos' URLs.

I have tried searching stack overflow and other but i am unable to find the exact solution.

Comment: is the URL local or online?

Comment: online, on a remote server

Comment: and do you know what is the full URL in the server? if so, I will post code to display image from URL